# Token Not Working On Auto Node Title and Auto Entity Title

Tags: 7, tokens, nodes

I am using drupal 7, auto node title 7.x-1.0, and token 7.x-1.4. I am trying to hide content type title field and set title value based on other field value, so i use auto-node title and token module. But, when i try to set the default value of the title using token, the token didn't work.

Then, after searching for a while, i've found this post:
[Token replacement pattern is not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/token-replacement-pattern-is-not-working)

So, i try to install auto entity title 7.x-1.1 module and disable my auto node title. But, the token still not working. Anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work indeed... It has to do with the way Drupal saves nodes. It starts with the title, and then reads and writes the rest of the fields.

The quick and dirty way is to use the rules module, and on node creation or edit, save the node again. I have been using this technique and can confirm it works.